# Sql Server Full Text Index Ranking Multiple Indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

We have several parts of our system that we have added a full text index to such as forums, news, etc.  These are unrelated to each other but we have a site wide search functionality that returns results from each of these full text indexes.

My question is how do I rank these to show the most relevant as the ranking scores I am getting are unrelated or is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks for any help.